# Use BeautifulSoup to scrape multiple websites

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I try to get tickers for multiple websites using BeautifulSoup. I tried the following code with a loop but when I run the output it only gives me one ticker for one website:

```
url = ['https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/AAPL/key-statistics/', 'https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/BOX/key-statistics/']

for pg in url: 
    page = requests.get(pg)

soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, "html.parser")

ticker = soup.find("h1", attrs={"data-reactid":"7"}).text

ticker
```

Output:

```
Out[147]: 'BOX - Box, Inc.'
```

I then tried to use append function:

```
data = [ ]
data.append(ticker)
```

but still gives me only one result. Anything wrong here?

Comment: Please format your code using the "Code Sample" button.

Comment: And I take it you mean "scrape"?

Comment: sorry not familiar with it... just made some edit..

Comment: Was the "page = " command really the only thing that was inside of your "for" loop?  Or did you mean to indent that too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is perfect.What you have done you have kept `soup` outside the for loop hence it is taking only `last url` rather all `urls`. Now try this.

```
url = ['https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/AAPL/key-statistics/', 'https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/BOX/key-statistics/']

for pg in url:
    page = requests.get(pg)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, "html.parser")
    ticker = soup.find("h1", attrs={"data-reactid":"7"}).text
    print("Output :- " + ticker)
```

Output:-

```
Output :- AAPL - Apple Inc.
Output :- BOX - Box, Inc.
```

Comment: Before the OP was formatted as code, it was assumed that all of that was in the "for" loop, which means it was grabbing the the new content (see Maaz's example).  I think the problem was that the "`data = [ ]`" command was inside of the loop.

Answer (score 3):

Your code is not correctly indent, but when I run this:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

url = ['https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/AAPL/key-statistics/', 'https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/BOX/key-statistics/']

data = []
for pg in url:
    page = requests.get(pg)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, "html.parser")
    ticker = soup.find("h1", attrs={"data-reactid":"7"}).text
    data.append(ticker)

print(data)
```

I get this:

`['AAPL - Apple Inc.', 'BOX - Box, Inc.']`

Comment: I did the same just before I saw this answer, and I got the same result.  @user11035529, if your "`data = []`" command is inside of the loop, then it just re-creates "`data`" as a brand new list every time before it appends anything.

Comment: @BillM. Indeed :-)